# How can I modify CSS color sets in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: css, colors, syntax, sublimetext2

In Sublime Text 2, for a specific theme, I want to have one color for the attribute and one color for the value.

```
background:#FFF url('some/img.png') 10px 10px;
```

`background`______  (the attribute name) should be a color

`#FFF url('some/img.png') 10px 10px`  ____________ (the values) should be another color (one color for the entire value).

I know I have to modify the theme color set, but anyone have any idea how?

And one other thing, I don't want space after the colon (when hitting tab)

I want "float:left;" instead of "float: left;". Does anyone know where can I set this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it is currently too broad; it's asking two separate things, and you've accepted an answer which only answers the secondary question, not the primary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about the color attribute and value yet, but for the css spacing I may have an answer. Go to `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\CSS\css_completions.py` Line 190. Change `l.append((p, p + ": "))` to `l.append((p, p + ":"))`

Answer (score 3):

check this out http://tmtheme-editor.herokuapp.com/
this is very useful to style your elements .. however if you like your current theme and you only want to edit the tag,class,id ... etc in CSS then you have to edit the theme file you are using .. generally this is in `Sublime Text 2\Packages\Color Scheme - Default\skin-name`

after that you have to edit or add if they dont exist the following rules:

```
<dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>css tag-name</string>
        <key>scope</key>
        <string>meta.selector.css entity.name.tag</string>
        <key>settings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>foreground</key>
            <string>#9EFFFF</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>css#id</string>
        <key>scope</key>
        <string>meta.selector.css entity.other.attribute-name.id</string>
        <key>settings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>foreground</key>
            <string>#FFB454</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>css.class</string>
        <key>scope</key>
        <string>meta.selector.css entity.other.attribute-name.class</string>
        <key>settings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>foreground</key>
            <string>#5FE461</string>
            <key>fontStyle</key>
            <string> underline</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>css property-name:</string>
        <key>scope</key>
        <string>support.type.property-name.css</string>
        <key>settings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>foreground</key>
            <string>#9DF39F</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>css property-value;</string>
        <key>scope</key>
        <string>meta.property-group support.constant.property-value.css, meta.property-value support.constant.property-value.css</string>
        <key>settings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>foreground</key>
            <string>#F6F080</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>css @at-rule</string>
        <key>scope</key>
        <string>meta.preprocessor.at-rule keyword.control.at-rule</string>
        <key>settings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>foreground</key>
            <string>#F6AA11</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>css additional-constants</string>
        <key>scope</key>
        <string>meta.property-value support.constant.named-color.css, meta.property-value constant</string>
        <key>settings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>foreground</key>
            <string>#EDF080</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>css constructor.argument</string>
        <key>scope</key>
        <string>meta.constructor.argument.css</string>
        <key>settings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>foreground</key>
            <string>#EB939A</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

and of course you can fill in the values what colors u like